# ArrayAdapter getView returns NullPointerException -

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I'm new to android, I've tried many solutions but nothing works!

Can you please see what's wrong with my code:

I get `NullPointerException` in `holder.CardContent.setText(card.getString("content"));`

I've tried to change `layoutInflater` from `null` to `parent`, `false`
The ids are not the false one!

**`CardAdapter.java`**

```
public class CardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> {
    protected Context mContext;
    protected List<ParseObject> mCards;

    public CardAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> cards) {
        super(context, R.layout.card_item, cards);

        mContext = context;
        mCards = cards;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.card_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.CardContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardText);
        } else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ParseObject card = mCards.get(position);

        holder.CardContent.setText(card.getString("content")); // <-- NPE here.

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder{
        TextView CardContent;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
at com.kardapps.lifehacks.activities.CardAdapter.getView(CardAdapter.java:64)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
.......
```

Comment: @NamelessOne your links are completely irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `convertView`'s tag to the `holder` in your `if`-block.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.card_item, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.CardContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardText);

    // Add this line
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
```

You can see that in the `else`-block, you're retrieving the tag and casting it to `ViewHolder`. If you haven't set the tag, `getTag()` returns null, causing the Exception.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `holder` is `null` at least for the beginning.
`card` could be `null` too but its not clear at the moment.

Although the adapter recycling logic is right you have forgotten to `setTag` to the `View`.

The logic of the recycling is that the way you scroll you save (using `setTag`) the already read/seen data to the view (here `convertView`).

Then each time you pass the same position you use `setTag` to retrieve them instead of recreating them (`LayoutInflater.from...`)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        //                      This is not an error but using parent you avoid Lint warnings 
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent); 
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.CardContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardText);
        convertView.setTag(holder); // <-- As suggested for improvement
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ParseObject card = mCards.get(position);

    holder.CardContent.setText(card.getString("content")); // <-- NPE here.

    // convertView.setTag(holder); // <-- This line is missing
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I think the convertView.setTag(holder); should be inside the if-block as mentioned by @Mike M

Comment: It could be! Its quite redundant to set it when its already set. I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

See this code:

```
if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.card_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.CardContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardText);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    ParseObject card = mCards.get(position);
    holder.CardContent.setText(card.getString("content"));
```

Two possibilities:

- if convertView is not null, you are just initialising holder object and not cardContent.
- `mCards.get(position);` returns null